# Restoring lost commits in git

Tags: git

I have a **local** repository, let's call that `A`.

In `A` I have lots of LOST_FOUND's that I want to restore. 
What would be the best (and least dangerous) way of restoring said commits?

(I can't really say why they're lost, I honestly thought I was doing a simple "commit, go home for the day"-kinda operation, but apparently it became something else.

**EDIT:** Doing a `git branch foundit LOST_FOUND_N` results in

```
error: Object #SHA1 is a blob, not a commit
fatal: Not a valid branch point: `LOST_FOUND_N`.
```

(Where `#SHA1` is a, well, `SHA1`, and `N` is the number of the `LOST_FOUND`)

**EDIT 2:** Doing a `git show` on the LOST_FOUND_-files shows that they mostly map to the files that I've lost (but not all of them seem to belong to the same commit (as far as I can tell, I can't remember exactly what I've commited each time), or even the same branch).

Comment: I think you should share more details in order to get useful response. How did you lose these commits? Did you lose them in a local repository or in a remote one?

Comment: Ah, thanks for responding, wasn't completely sure what to include.
The repo is a local one, I rarely push anything other than production code. As for how I lost them, that's a big mystery since it's several days ago.

Comment: But basically, I thought I was doing a simple "commit, go home for the day", but apparently I did something else.

Comment: If you're sure you committed these changes (it's mostly impossible to restore something that wasn't committed) you can check `git reflog`. It shows extended history of your repository. Most interesting to you should be entries saying 'commit ...'. If you're lucky you'll be able to find your commits in reflog by their messages. Then we can think about further steps.

Comment: The changes were commited, that much I know. The problem is that `git reflog` doesn't show the commits.

Comment: Before doing anything else you should maybe backup your current `.git` folder containing all the data. To do that run e.g. `tar cfvz ../repo_git.tar.gz .git/`. Seems indicated to me as you already lost data by doing some apparently harmless actions.

Comment: That was (fortunately) the first thing I did when the (small) part of me that's cautious noticed that something was missing. Also, I've got raw backups of the directory scheduled every 2 hours at daytime, so I'll probably survive (and of course did I make and commit the changes in-between one of those).

Comment: Also, I just solved it by manually inspecting each file with `git show FILE` and then, when I recognized the file, a `git show FILE > ORIGINAL_FILENAME`. But it would still be nice to have the original directory restored..

Answer (score 4):

I've got the following alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias gitkall='git fsck --lost-found | awk "{ print \$3 ; }" | xargs gitk --all'
```

It makes a command gitkall, which shows every revision in the repository, including those which are left over from history edits etc.

From the gitk gui, it's easy and intuitive to tag interesting lost revisions, make new branches etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just go ahead and answer this myself:

Note that this answer is specific to this question, and not a universal solve-by-magick:

1. Inspect the file with

   `git show FILE`
2. When you recognize the file, pipe it like so:

   `git show FILE > FILENAME`

Do note that this only give you *the contents of the files you find, not the structure of the directory.*